# Run data lines next to hvac lines, outside of conduit

Tags: wiring, data-wiring

I'm wondering if I can run some data lines along side of some HVAC lines. There's a hole in the side of the house that leads to a large bulkhead that runs the length of the basement. This is where the hvac lines from the compressor enter the house.

I'm trying to avoid poking another hole in the house and was wondering if I can run some data lines (cat5/6 and coax) through the same hole. It's not a conduit so I *think* it's okay from a code perspective, but figured I'd ask the experts.

[image]

Comment: By "HVAC lines" I assume you mean pipes/hoses, not wires.

Comment: Def pipes/hoses, but I think the power cable is also part of that bundle. Not sure though.

Comment: You shouldn't run a data cable in the same bundle with power wires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but you risk network problems when the A/C-heatpump gets worked on.

Be sure to use outdoor-rated data cables.

Comment: Good point. The data cables are actually the ones running along side the house. They just go into the house in a less convenient place for setting up the termination hardware than if they went into the same place as the hvac connections and/or their own hole near by.